# NP++ double click highlighting to include "backslash" but only on the left

Tags: notepad++, latex, highlighting

I work with LaTeX files a lot and I find myself using NP++ every now and then. I mainly use my LaTeX editor.

There is a neat option in my editor that allows double clicking to highlight "\" but only on the left.

For example, double clicking "\MacroOne\MacroTwo" will highlight either "\MacroOne" or "\MacroTwo".

NP++ has a feature to include "\" as a word for double clicking purposes Settings>Preferences>Delimiter, but NP++ would highlight "\MacroOne\MacroTwo" whereas I would prefer to have the highlighting behavior that I'm used to.

My question is: Is it possible to adjust the highlighting behavior of NP++? Is it possible to achieve the desired behavior I described above?

I appreciate any advice or resources I should look into.

Comment: What you ask is quite a special behavior. Did you think about modifying source code of Notepad++ and adding your very specifiec requirements there?